# I am new to operating system, What is size of IDT?

Tags: x86, interrupt, osdev

6 bytes are required to store the interrupt gate descriptor, each descriptor comprises of  32 bits of segment selector and 16 bits of offset. What is the size in bytes of the Interrupt Descriptor Table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, you have 256 entries (because there's only 256 possible interrupts per CPU); so if an entry is 8 bytes (protected mode) the IDT limit would be 2047 (and 4095 in long mode because entries are 16 bytes).

However:

- for ancient computers (single-CPU, no IO APICs) you only need 48 entries (32 entries for exceptions plus 16 entries for PIC chip IRQs)
- for "unusual situations" (e.g. temporary boot code) you can cheat (use general protection fault exception's error code to determine the interrupt/IRQ number when the IDT entry didn't exist/was beyond IDT's limit); and get by with 14 IDT entries (enough for general protection fault and nothing higher).
- in theory, you can dynamically adjust the size of the IDT (e.g. start with enough space for 256 entries but only allocate RAM for 48 entries, then auto-detect hardware capabilities and increase the size of IDT by allocating more RAM and adjusting IDT limit). This is mostly never worth the hassle (e.g. the additional code to adjust the size of the IDT might cost you more RAM than you save)

Note that for large servers it can make sense to have different IDTs for different NUMA domains or different CPUs; to avoid a "maximum of 256-32-some IRQs from devices per computer" limit (and get a "maximum of 256-32-some IRQs from devices per NUMA domain or per CPU" limit instead). Don't forget that each PCI device that supports MSI can (in theory) want a group of up to 16 IRQs; so a global limit of "about 220 IRQs maybe" can (in theory) become a problem (for finding/allocating free IDT entries) when there's 14 or more PCI devices; and due to the way interrupt priorities work (for APICs) a single global IDT can (in theory) start to be "less than ideal" with as little as 2 PCI devices (e.g. if they both want 16 interrupts and both "need" the same interrupt priorities). In practice, it's unlikely that all PCI devices will want so many interrupts, so "in practice" isn't as bad as "in theory".

Note: "maximum of 256-32-some IRQs" comes from a maximum of 256 IDT entries, minus 32 entries for exceptions, minus some miscellaneous entries (for inter-processor interrupts, spurious IRQs and maybe kernel API if it uses a software interrupt).